# Do Adobe Air apps support multicore processing?

Tags: air, multicore

Do Adobe apps support multiple cores or do they still use single core?

So will it make a difference in speed (in performance of the application) if I'm using a Pentium 4 processor (3 ghz) v/s a Dual Core Processor (2.7 ghz)

---

**Edit:**
*As mentioned by [AndrejaKo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334748/andrejako) in his comment below, I have already asked this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/183883/do-adobe-air-apps-support-multicore-processing/183934#183934) but I was hoping that some Air developers here would have more information regarding this question.*

Comment: Just a note in case someone decides to vote to move: We've already had this question on SuperUser, but nobody was able to provide a recent (as in for newest version) source claiming that Adobe AIR does or does not support multithreading. We've hoping that someone here programmed in AIR and can enlighten us.

Comment: i'll make a note of that in my original post,

Comment: If that dual core processor is not a Pentium D it definitely will make a difference, but not because it's dual core.

Comment: Its a Dual Core Pentium (R) processor E5400

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Air developer, but all the documentation I was able to find indicates that, no, Air does not currently support true concurrency... though they're considering the ups and downs of leaving Web Workers in their borrowed copy of WebKit for a future release.

- [Is multi-threading possible in Flash or ActionScript?](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Is_multi_threading_possible_in_Flash_or_ActionScri-12026.html)
- [WebKit features not supported in Air 1.x](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-67c0013e126afbe6c4d-8000.html)
- [Adobe AIR 2 Beta Now Available: "Does that mean we can use web workers in Air?"](http://blogs.adobe.com/air/2009/11/adobe_air_2_beta_now_available.html#comment-389)

I think that last one covers the version of AIR you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe does not provide any ActionScript or JavaScript APIs for working with threads. So, everything written in one of those languages will definitely be executed single-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

With adobe air 3.4 release, adobe will support concurrency using a new workers api.

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423